# MathNet.Numerics operation return types

Tags: c#, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I'm using MathsNet.Numerics lib. I want to do operations on Complex Vectors i.e. I'm
`using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Complex`
which gives me `Vector` as Complex version of `MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Generic.Vector<T>`
Operatations on `Vector`s however don't return objects assignable to `Vector`:

```
Complex[] complexData = new Complex[n]
... fill data, fft etc ...
Vector vectorReference = new DenseVector(complexData);
vectorReference = vectorReference.Conjugate(); // Error.
```

> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type
>   '`MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Generic.Vector<System.Numerics.Complex>`'
>   to '`MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Complex.Vector`'

Why are the return values of methods that operate on `Vector`s (e.g. `Conjugate` and `PointwiseMultiply`) not assignable to `Vector`s?

Comment: Any reason you reverted my edit that improved the spelling and formatting?

Comment: Sorry Stijn - we did a simaltanious edit and I lost a change - feel free to re apply.

Comment: No problem, sometimes simultaneous edits can't merge correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Type hierarchy: `Vector<T> <- Complex.Vector <- Complex.DenseVector`

.Net doesn't support specializing the return type (covariance) when overriding a method, so we technically cannot modify `Conjugate` to return `Complex.Vector` or even `Complex.DenseVector` in a derived type.

In general we recommend to expect and work with generic types only (i.e. `Vector<Complex>`) in fields and method arguments - or when you intend to reuse variables. In Math.NET Numerics v3 this has been streamlined, so there will almost never be a need to use the actual implementation types.